# Update table on Trigger

Tags: database, triggers, mariadb

I need to set a trigger on a mariadb table that, when a record is updated, would update the DateModifica field to the current time of the record itself

the SQL code should be

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_DateMod
     AFTER UPDATE
     ON table1
     ...
BEGIN
     UPDATE table1
     SET DateMod = current_timestamp()
     WHERE id = ...
END
```

I hope someone will help me in debugging the code
Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever it is possible, you should define the trigger in the table itself:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 CHANGE DateModifica
      DateModifica TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: SOLVED - Thanks for the replies. I solved

Comment: If it's solved, don't forget to mark it as answered.